# AVPlayercontroller - Adding Overlay Subviews

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

Depends upon the PlaybackControl Visibity How to show and hide the Custom Subview added in contentOverlayView?

I want to do like Youtube TVOS app did.

I tried with UIPressesEvent but it is not giving me the exact touch events. It is giving me these:

```
  override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for item in presses {
        switch item.type {
        case .Menu:
            self.customViews.alpha = 0
        case .PlayPause:
            self.player?.pause()
            self.customViews.alpha = 0
        default:
            self.setVisibilityToPreviewView()
        }
      }
    }

 func setVisibilityToPreviewView () { //This wont work in all cases.
      if self.previewView.alpha == 1 {
         self.previewView.alpha = 0
      } else {
         self.previewView.alpha = 1
      }
    }
```

But with this Touch events i can only show and hide the subviews.
It should be hidden when the **playbackcontrol** is **Hidden**.

If I get the **PlayBackControl Visibility** values I don't need to worry about hiding these subviews.

Apple is Using **AVNowPlayingPlaybackControlsViewController**. It is not open for developers.

So I need to find some other better way to do this.

Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: This question is unclear. Please elaborate on your problem statement and what you have tried already.

Comment: @JAL I tried this much can you give some guidelines

Answer (score 4):

You can register a tapGesture recognizer and then set its `allowPressTypes` property to `UIPressType.Select`,  something like this

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onSelect:")
tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)];
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

And inside your action button show or hide custom overlays.

**Example:** Add this code inside a view controller and on tap (selecting at empty area on front of remote, touch area) you will see a message on console.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onSelect")
        tapGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)]
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);
    }
    func onSelect(){
        print("this is select gesture handler method");
    }
```

**Update:** Below is the code which will create AVPlayerController and will register tapGestureRecognizer to playervc.view.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playContent()
    }
    func playContent(){
        let urlString = "<contentURL>"
        guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else{
            return
        }
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerVC.player = avPlayer
        self.playerObj = playerVC

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onSelect")
        tapGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)]
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);

        playerVC.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil);

    }
```

Give a try to this, I think it should work fine.

Comment: This is for TVOS. And am using Remote control. In AVPlayerViewController how i can add this gesture. If i am adding this to self.view it is not working.. so did that to ContentOverlayview. that too not working

Comment: Yes I know that its TVOS and it should work. Add it to whatever view is on top.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to get visibility of PLAYBACKCONTROL in player. Need to check its visibility and hide the contents.

Comment: You can check yourCustomView.hidden value for any view to check if its hidden or visible.

Comment: if PlaybackControl is hidden - Hide the subviews otherwise it should be visible. we can't go with yourCustomView.hidden value. Please check my updated Question.

Comment: There is no public API for that or Notification which will specifically tell you that you Playback Controls are now visible. I would suggest that you create some functionality by keep state of the player in context that when playback controls will be visible. Like touch, press & player states.